# Python, Bazel: Unittest in same folder as *submodule* named `math`: standard `math` is shadowed on Ubuntu, but not Mac?

Tags: python, module, bazel, shadowing, built-in

We have `example_package`, which is a Python module itself, so we can access `example_package.my_module` in code. We also defined `example_package.math`, since we have some simple math routines.  We have some tests, which Bazel will effectively place in the same directory as these submodule files.

When we do this, *any* tests that Bazel generates in that directory which are Python binaries will have `math` shadowed on Mac, but not on Ubuntu.

Reproduction steps:
https://github.com/EricCousineau-TRI/repro/blob/b08bc47/bug/mac_builtin_shadow/test.sh#L38

Why is this?

#### Bazel Background

In Bazel, we you decide to effectively place our unittests in the same package (`BUILD.bazel` file) as our modules. Bazel will generate wrapper Python scripts (for adjusting environment variables, unpacking archives, etc.), and place them according to the name of the test.

As an example, in `//example_package`, if I define `py_library(name = "my_module", ...)`, and then define `py_test(name = "my_module_test", srcs = ["test/my_module_test.py"], ...)` in that same package, Bazel will generate a file `./bazel-bin/example_package/my_module_test` (which is reflecting what is in `.runfiles`) - note that it is not under `./bazel-bin/example_package/test/my_module_test`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer stems from these posts:
https://bugs.python.org/issue32845
https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/8041

Quoting a summary from the GitHub post:

> According to Eric V. Smith and Ned Deily on the Python bug tracker,
>   this is expected behavior. `math` is a *standard* library, but not a
>   *builtin* library per the standards. Ubuntu is adding extra modules to the builtins list, while Mac stays true to the "truth".
>
> Ned posted an example showing `math` being builtin on Ubuntu, but a
>   non-builtin on Mac. If you print `sys.builtin_module_names`, you'll
>   see that Ubuntu does this for a few other libraries.